# Reading nodes data from local variable in d3

Tags: json, d3.js

How to create a d3 graph from local variable `jsonNodes` (JSON data) rather than reading from a file, the example I am using [Andrew-Reid’s online example on bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/46e300b5f2ad4af350fbd01ffec3e25d).

Following is the code I am trying, the button 'Go' is calling the `refresh` function to refresh the graph by using the `jsonNodes` variable. ( I am actually calling a WebSocket service to get the `jsonNodes` populated but as of now i have just hardcoded it in the function).

when I click the 'Go' button, it does nothing.

```
  <canvas width="960" height="500"></canvas>
  <body>
      <button id="refresh" onclick="refresh();">Go</button>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
      width = canvas.width,
      height = canvas.height;

  var jsonNodes;

  function refresh(){
    jsonNodes =  {
    "nodes": [
      {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
      {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
      {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1} ],
      "links": [
      {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1} ]
       } ;

        simulation
        .nodes(jsonNodes.nodes)
        .force("link")
        .links(jsonNodes.links);   
  };

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  d3.json("../data/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links);

    d3.select(canvas)
        .call(d3.drag()
            .container(canvas)
            .subject(dragsubject));

    function ticked() {
      var margin = 20;
      graph.nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
        d.x = Math.max(margin, Math.min(width - margin, d.x))
        d.y = Math.max(margin, Math.min(height - margin, d.y))
      })

      context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

      context.beginPath();
      graph.links.forEach(drawLink);
      context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
      context.stroke();

      context.beginPath();
      graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode);
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
      context.stroke();
    }

    function dragsubject() {
      return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
    }
  });

  function drawLink(d) {
    context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
    context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
  }

  function drawNode(d) {
    context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
    context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  }
  </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Is jsonNodes a global variable? Could you post a little more complete code which you have going so that we know where you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your updated post with the sample code, there are few things which may be causing failure to achieve desired results. 
Firstly, I can see that the jsonNodes is an object in the desired format already.
 Secondly, since the data is already in the desired format in a variable, you do not need to parse it in using `d3.json("../data/miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;`.

Also in the example by Andrew Reid, he uses the object `graph`, which in your case would `jsonNodes`. So where ever, you see `graph.nodes` or `graph.links` replace that with `jsonNodes.nodes` and `jsonNodes.links`. A simpler alternative to changing all individual locations of this is to transfer the data from `jsonNodes` to a variable called `graph`, and use the `graph` variable as in Andrew Reid's example.

Lastly, the order of you declaring simulation is wrong. You are calling

```
    simulation
        .nodes(jsonNodes.nodes)
        .force("link")
        .links(jsonNodes.links);   
  };
```

before

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

This is opposite.

Here is a plunker with everything fixed for you:
https://plnkr.co/edit/LcsGes?p=preview

Some other examples: http://jsfiddle.net/DavidHoksza/0d7en4po/ which directly uses data in a variable. However, keep in mind that this example uses d3 v3 and the syntax for the force simulation has changed. There are many more examples which use variable directly in force simulations: http://blockbuilder.org/kenpenn/268878b410ddb1201277be3f0305d566
You can search for more examples using http://blockbuilder.org/search

I hope this helps. If not please create plunker / block for me to check what you have going exactly. And populate more data into the jsonNodes variable.